# Max size of a Method Java

Tags: java, methods, size, max

I have a java file having one method that is very big, it compile successfully, but after running it throws java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 72521 in class file

I research on vm spec file [JVM](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/vmspec/2nd-edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659) restricts the maximum size of a method to 65536 bytes. The JVM spec has mentioned about this restriction

Is there is any work around for this ?

Comment: Actually, the maximum size of a method is 65535 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably split your method into two or more sub-methods, which you call in sequence from the main one.  In fact, it should probably be way more than two.  Encapsulating your code into multiple methods will make it muuuuuch easier to understand than one Dickens-length method.  And hey, you might be able to re-use them elsewhere.

If you absolutely can't break up your method, maybe you could try taking out extraneous whitespace?  This is called [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29), and there's probably a utility that will do it for Java.  All of this is with the caveat that it will make your epic method even less readable, so don't do this if you're going to want to change it in the future ever ever.

On a related note, congratulations on writing a method so long you broke java.  That's actually really impressive.

Comment: In the scenario like where the code regeneration is done automatically in that scenario whats needs to done,

Comment: Now that I think more about it, it's unlikely that minification will do anything since your source files are being compiled to bytecode, in a way that's probably independent of what kind of whitespace you used.  So, never mind on that suggestion.

Comment: @anish: Do you mean that the code that's too large is being generated automatically by another application?  If that's true it could be more of a problem.  If it's an application that you wrote then you'll need to think harder about how the generated code should be encapsulated automatically.  If you're not the author of the application you may need to go through the code yourself and encapsulate it manually, which will be time-consuming.  Also, file a bug report with whoever makes the app.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, split your method up into smaller ones!

Answer (score 3):

No, not without compiling your own version of the JVM to use larger size integers for storing the indices/attributes which are currently limiting it. Then I suspect you'd need to have your custom version of the JDK which would compile it. And after all that, your program would run only on your hacked up JVM.

There is not really any reason you would need any single method this large.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this on a server software while trying playing around with profiling -Xrunhprof. With the latest build of jre7 on 64bit win7, -Xrunhprof did some magic which made the method too large.